# How can Ez Macros work on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, macros

**EZ Macros** (a nice software that records "keyboard macros") **doesn't work on Windows 8 (64-bits)**, and I am looking for a way to make it work.

When we try to record a macro, we can see the message **"unable to set the hook"**.

I know that Windows 8 has a "macro software", but I have many macros in Ez Macros, then I need it to work on this OS.

**I think that is missing a DLL** 
I put Hook.dll, downloaded from http://www.dll-files.com , but it's not working yet. Maybe because it's 64bits. But I remember that this nice software works on Windows 7 64bits...
I am investigating, when I can :). **Any idea or maybe a dll for 64bits, tell us!.**

I did but still the same... :
*1. Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > **Change User Account Control Settings (UAC).**
2. Once there, move the slider to **Never Notify**.*

More information: 
It use to work on Windows 7 w7 64bits...

Thaks all

Comment: if it doesn't work, it doesn't work. I don't understand how you want anyone to solve this.

Comment: no idea if this will work but try running it as administrator?

Comment: @Sickest You ask how anyone is meant to solve a question of why something doesn't work? Is that a philosophical question? Like, do you think nobody has ever asked a question like why doesn't something work and had a solution? I don't know how you can think that. Maybe somebody knows what that message means and/or knows a workaround. Or maybe somebody uses the software they ask about, if it has quite a user base. It's not like if something doesn't work it doesn't work. Sometimes that's true but not always. And there can often be workarounds / alternative solutions.

Comment: I check their website: `All of our programs have been tested with Windows 7, Vista, XP, 2003, 2000, NT, 95, 98, and Me.` They haven't updated their software for windows 8 support, hence my previous comment.

Comment: Most likely it's not Windows 8 that's your problem, it's the 64-bit part and the fact that the latest EZ Macros is like 5+ years old now (2008).  Have you [contacted the authors](http://www.americansys.com/ContactU.htm) yet to enquire about a release date for 64-bit compatible version?

Comment: I did not contact the authors because I read (I don't remember where) that people try to contact but didn't have answer. I think that is missing a DLL...

Comment: The "Dependency Walker" tool reliably identifies missing DLL dependencies (It's the reason why the tool was originally written)